# Why does sklearn.roc_curve return varying shapes for fpr and tpr and thresholds with varying random states?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In sklearn.roc_curve the results returned are fpr, tpr and thresholds.

Despite drop_intermediate set to False, the shapes of fpr, tpr and thresholds
change with random states.

Why is that?

As an example, I have:

- test_labels and predicted_probabilities are (158,).
- fpr, tpr and thresholds are (149,), in another run they are (146,).

Answer (score 3):

the internal algorithm eliminates repeated scores from thresholds, so if you have repeated entries whose scores are exactly equal then they will be removed.

Comment: In https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186337/average-roc-for-repeated-10-fold-cross-validation-with-probability-estimates they calculate they mean ROC (for cross validation) with np.mean. Wouldn't a dropped score influence the mean that you get vs. when it wouldn't be dropped?

Comment: you should not use np.mean unless all curves have the same X axis, so you must resample the result on a finer grid using linear interpolation before you take the mean,

Comment: your linked post has done that when he used `np.interp`.

Comment: As a quick side question: Interpolation in ROCs is allowed because we assume the values in between exist, right?

Comment: yes, for a given tpr, there exists 2 values of fpr, so if there can be two possible values for the fpr for a given tpr then intermediate values of fpr can exist too, which is an approximation that will hold if the number of samples is large enough (like more than 10) that the difference between the two fpr values is small.

Comment: Thanks! Is there some website that visualizes or explains this further?